# Adding to browsers history on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the plugin called Ascensor from http://kirkas.ch/ascensor
It's basically a tool that help me build a single page application.

However, I have a problem that I don't know how to solve.

All of my content will be listet inside my `<div id="ascensorBuilding">`

```
<div id="ascensorBuilding">
        <div class="floor floor-1">
            <span class="text">Floor 1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="floor floor-2">
            <span class="text">Floor 2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="floor floor-3">
            <span class="text">Floor 3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="floor floor-4">
            <span class="text">Floor 4</span>
        </div>
        <div class="floor floor-5">
            <span class="text">Floor 5</span>
        </div>
        <div class="floor floor-6">
            <span class="text">Floor 6</span>
        </div>
        <div class="floor floor-7">
            <span class="text">Floor 7</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

And my floor links:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="links-to-floor">
        <li><a>Floor 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Floor 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Floor 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Floor 4</a></li>
        <li><a>Floor 5</a></li>
        <li><a>Floor 6</a></li>
        <li><a>Floor 7</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And I then use this script to change between the "pages"

```
var ascensor = $('#ascensorBuilding').ascensor({ascensorFloorName:["Home", "About", "HTML" , "Jquery" , "CSS", "Smartphone", "End"], direction: [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0]]});
        var ascensorInstance = $('#ascensorBuilding').data('ascensor');

        $(".links-to-floor li").click(function(event, index) {
            ascensorInstance.scrollToFloor($(this).index());
        });

        $(".links-to-floor li:eq("+ ascensor.data("current-floor") +")").addClass("selected");

        ascensor.on("scrollStart", function(event, floor){
            $(".links-to-floor li").removeClass("selected");
            $(".links-to-floor li:eq("+floor.to+")").addClass("selected");
});
```

As you can see I add a floorname to my url. So I will start on `www.mysite.com/index.html#home` and if I go to another page, it would be `www.mysite.com/index.html#about` for example.

And if I manually put `www.mysite.com/index.html#about` in the addressbar, I will also go to that specific page.

**But my problem is** that if I click around my floors, non of the pages are added to the browsers history. So if I decide to click on the browsers back button, I will go back the site I was on before entering my website.

How can I manage to add my click to the browsers history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the Javascript history object yourself:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries